# cmake subdirectories fortran Project

Tags: cmake, fortran, subdirectory

I have a project developed under FORTRAN. To organize the project I have decomposed it in subdirectories. Then, I would use Cmake files to generate Makefiles.
The hierarchy of the project is:
Main_directory
|____lib
|____inc
|____src
             |__src1
                 |__src2
                 |__src3
|____tests
                |___test1.f90
                |___test2.f90

The lib directory content compiled static lib files (. a), Inc contain include files (. h), and src content Fortran source files. Thus, source files in src folder depend between them during compilation, and file in src2 can use variables or function, from file in src1 and uses also lib and include files. Since, the source files in the source directory (src) are compiled they will be used by a source file(test1.f90 or test2.f90) that generate executable in test directory.
I'm newbie with Cmake so I would like to know how to write Cmake files for the main folder and subdirectories.
thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: And don't mix compiled stuff with sources. Path to the precompiled dependencies should be detected during the compilation. The results of the compilation live in the build tree.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt  I'dont Know from where I must begin,  in this case it appear more difficult. In explaining course or tutor they show only the case of library with one directory for source files. <\br>

Comment: @Velkan  you mean that libs will be detected during compilation?

Comment: If you write or get somewhere the CMake scripts for their detection - they will be. (but you've got bigger problems for now)

Comment: Probably compile a library from each directory like src1, src2, etc with `add_library()`. Make an executable in test1 with `add_executable()` and link libraries to it with `target_link_libraries()`.